# How to delete row form ajax when it is deleted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parent-child, delete-row

[image]

hello i am trying to delete a row with check box delete when i delete any record it is deleting from database and i can see with refreshing page.

I want to delete the row without refresh how can i achieve that:
This is my listing code:

```
<tbody>
    <?php while($staffResults=$staffQuery->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="staff-list" name="checked" value="<?php echo $staffResults['id_staff']; ?>"></td>
            <td><?php echo $staffResults['staff_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $staffResults['staff_email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $staffResults['staff_phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php  $datetime = $staffResults['staff_registered'];
            echo  date("d-m-Y", strtotime($datetime));   ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

And delete button:

```
<button type="button" id="deleteStaffList" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
```

Here is my script and ajax code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">  
    $("#deleteStaffList").click(function()
    {
        $("#delshowMessageDiv").hide();
        $("#delshowMessage").html('');
        var deleteStaffList = $('.staff-list:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('value');
        }).get().join(",");
        console.log(deleteStaffList); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "staffcontroller.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { delData : deleteStaffList, 'action':'delete'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if(response["success"]==true)
                {
                    $("#delshowMessageDiv").hide();
                    $("#delshowSuccessMessageDiv").show();
                    $("#delshowSuccessMessage").html(response["message"]);
                    }else{
                    $("#delshowMessageDiv").show();
                    $("#delshowMessage").html(response["message"]);
                }   
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $("#delshowMessageDiv").show();
                $("#delshowMessage").html("OOPS! Something Went Wrong Please Try After Sometime!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Use jquery `.hide()` function for the desired rows

Comment: i wan to remove <tr> from listing

Comment: after success delete place following code:
`$('.staff-list:checkbox:checked').each(function(i,e){
 $(this).parents('tr').remove();
})` that is..

`if(response["success"]==true)
                {
                    $("#delshowMessageDiv").hide();
                    $("#delshowSuccessMessageDiv").show();
                    $("#delshowSuccessMessage").html(response["message"]);
                    }else{
                    $("#delshowMessageDiv").show();
                    $("#delshowMessage").html(response["message"]);
... YOU CAN PLACE CODE HERE...
                }`

Comment: @BharatBhatiya can you write in answer so that i can accept, can i write this in success function..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place 3 lines as follows: (// new lines -there comment- // till here)

```
    <script language="JavaScript">  
    $("#deleteStaffList").click(function()
    {
        $("#delshowMessageDiv").hide();
        $("#delshowMessage").html('');
        var deleteStaffList = $('.staff-list:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('value');
        }).get().join(",");
        console.log(deleteStaffList); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "staffcontroller.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { delData : deleteStaffList, 'action':'delete'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if(response["success"]==true)
                {
                    $("#delshowMessageDiv").hide();
                    $("#delshowSuccessMessageDiv").show();
                    $("#delshowSuccessMessage").html(response["message"]);
                    }else{
                    $("#delshowMessageDiv").show();
                    $("#delshowMessage").html(response["message"]);
                    // new lines
                    $('.staff-list:checkbox:checked').each(function(i,e){
                        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                    })
                    // till here
                    }   
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $("#delshowMessageDiv").show();
                $("#delshowMessage").html("OOPS! Something Went Wrong Please Try After Sometime!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: here document that will helps you : [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_parents.asp)